# How to completely change a string passed into a function in Python?

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I want to pass a variable to a function for changing, like this:

```py
def change(x):
    x="changed!"

y="hello"
change(y)
print(y) # hello
```

This is because you can only **mutate** variables when passing, but how can I completely change the variable?

Comment: You can't; strings are immutable, your function doesn't return anything, and you don't assign the result anyway.

Comment: @jonrsharpe : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pass-by-reference-vs-value-in-python says that you can mutate a variable, so a function can change it, but I want to fully change the variable, not just mutate it.

Comment: The only way is to return a new variable.  For mutable types such as lists, you could remove all the existing contents and add new ones, but you'd still have the same list object (with completely different contents).

Comment: In that example they use a list, which is mutable; strings aren't.

Comment: @jonrsharpe : yes, I understood.  And that's why I am asking this question.  Is there a way or not?  I just wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially add a global variable in the function like this:

```python
def change():
    global y
    y="changed!"

y="hello"
change()
print(y)
```

However, I wouldn't really recommend this as it could lead to minor bugs later on.

Comment: I was thinking of that but decided not to because it wouldn't work if `change` was called from a function.  I found out that I can't do this in any fully working way but thank you for your help 

Answer (score 0):

There are some data types in Python which are immutable (cannot be modified). These include strings, integers, floats, tuples... When you pass an immutable data type into a function, Python automatically passes it by value, as opposed to passing by reference. This means that you can't change the value of the original variable.

If you want to change the value, referencing by the original varable name, you'll need to return a value and assign it to the source variable by the same name. In the background, Python is actually creating a new value in a different memory location and pointing the variable to that.

```
def change(x):
    x="changed!"
    return x

y = "hello"
y = change(y)
print(y) # changed!
```